# Where is this gif of a girl turning into stone(?) and breaking apart from

Tags: haibane-renmei

I'm trying to find the title for this pic because I'm interested in watching it. If only I knew what it's called...

[image: Please help me find the title]

Comment: Reverse image search doesn't give any obvious results for me. From the coloring and animation I'd guess it's at least 10 years old, probably more. Where did you find it? Were there for example any tags at your source, that might help us identifying the anime?

Comment: I know, i've used reverse image too but no clue... the only think i've got is the link... (https://38.media.tumblr.com/f790161dced038bb8ae1db628d571997/tumblr_naj3dfu8JP1tq2uhdo1_500.gif)

Answer (score 16):

I'm not completely sure, but I think this is from one of the episodes towards the end of [*Haibane Renmei*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haibane_Renmei), where Reki, who is the character here

> finally is forced to confront her problems.

Off the top of my head, I don't remember the episode number. I'll try to look in the *Haibane Renmei* tag or the one for Reki on Tumblr to double-check this, since I think I've seen something like this there before.

The series is based off of some doujinshi by Yoshitoshi ABe, and follows the progress of a character named Rakka once she comes to an enclosed town and finds that she is one of the Haibane, who have grey wings and a disk on their heads.

Update: Wikipedia's [episode list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Haibane_Renmei_episodes) suggests that this is from the final episode (13), where

> [Reki] throws Rakka out of her studio, confronts a crumbling stone manifestation of herself, and relives her dream.

Rewatching the episode on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5Pg0uJQyL4) (beware of spoilers - this is the last episode), the build-up to the scene begins at around 4:50, [the actual scene](https://youtu.be/z5Pg0uJQyL4?t=13m15s) starts slightly after 13:15.